# JAVA Developing Instagram, Hashtag searching, algorithm to track interests of users based on their history

Tags: java, instagram, hashtag, user-tracking

I want to develop something like Instagram in Java.

1. How do I enable hashtag searching which finds posts with all the input hashtags?
2. How can I track interests of users with their histories (a simple algorithm)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will not get whole application here. you have to first try and show what you did and where you got stuck

Comment: I am not looking for a whole application, I am looking for examples of methods that handle the two points in my question.

Comment: for that you need to search on google.